# how to connect database multiple server in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

i build project in my local server but file database save in another server. i try edit in config database.php like this

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = '';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['database_two']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';
$db['database_two']['username'] = 'vtis';
$db['database_two']['password'] = '';
$db['database_two']['database'] = 'vtis';
$db['database_two']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
$db['database_two']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['database_two']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['database_two']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['database_two']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['database_two']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['database_two']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['database_two']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['database_two']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['database_two']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['database_two']['stricton'] = FALSE;
$db['database_two']['port'] = 5432;
```

but i don't know next step after that. can you tell me step by step how to connect database in another server with codeigniter?

munit_list.php

```
*/
class Munit_list extends CI_Model
{

    private $tbl_unit_list = 'unit_list';
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $CI=&get_instance();
        $CI->database_two = $this->load->database('database_two', TRUE);
        $this->database_two =& $CI->database_two; 
    }

    function get_all_unit_list()
    {
        $this->database_two->order_by('unit_id','desc');
        $data = $this->database_two->get($this->tbl_unit_list);
        return $data->result();
    }

}
```

i try model like this but its not working

Comment: try http://weblint4u.com/connecting-multiple-database-in-codeigniter/

Comment: had you try to debug to see whats happening?

Comment: i try var_dump($data);
   exit(); but browser not show anything but in firefox when i f12 show "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Answer (score 0):

its easy. Just this 3 lines:

```
$CI=&get_instance;
$CI->database_two = $this->load->database('database_two', TRUE);
$this->database_two =& $CI->database_two;
```

Comment: it depends on where you need it. If you need it just for one controller just add it into that controller. If you need it in more controllers...probably i would extend CI_CONTROLLER

Comment: yes, thats a good place if you will use it in more than 1 function

Comment: i try but it's not working well. i load in browser but display disappears and not show anything. any change in model?

Comment: oops, sorry. My bad. When i told CI_CONTROLLER i meant CI_MODEL.

Comment: ok. how about query use database_two? i try like this $data = $this->database_two->db->get($this->tbl_unit_list);
   return $data->result(); but its not working

Comment: because youre using ->db. just use database_two: `$data = $this->database_two->get($this->tbl_unit_list);`

Comment: Can you see the model that I have edited the code above? I've tried to like it but the display disappears and not show anything

Answer (score 0):

in your model in the construct function just add the database(s) you want to use. You can add as many as you like, as long as they are defined in your database file.

class Munit_list extends CI_Model {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->database_two= $this->load->database('database_two', TRUE); 
}
```

$this->database_two (can be any name you want to put it);
$this->load->database('database_two', TRUE);  'database_two' is the name you defined on your database file and the TRUE param is for the function to return the database object.

Then you can use it like:

```
function get_all_units_list(){
    $this->database_two->select("*");
    ....
    ....
}
```

More information in [CodeIgniter Connecting to your databases](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)